# How to extract from momentjs object date and time and join them to form new moment object?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have three momentjs object:

```
createdAt
startTime
endTime
```

I need to somehow extract from createdAt only date and from startTime and endTime only time and after that I need to join them in this fashion to create new moment object.

```
createdAt + startTime
createdAt + endTime
```

so the end results should look like that

```
"2019-05-30T21:44:44+02:00"
"2019-05-30T23:30:55+02:00"
```

You see here that date is the same but time is different. How can I achieve this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) on the desired objects and concatenate the resultant strings:

```
createdAt.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T' + startTime.format('HH:mm:ssZ');
createdAt.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T' + endTime.format('HH:mm:ssZ');
```